# How to restart an erlang node?

Tags: linux, erlang

A sample I have git push [github](https://github.com/mingchaoyan/sellaprime)

It is an example of application from the book Programming Erlang

you can do follow [README.md](https://github.com/mingchaoyan/sellaprime/blob/master/README.md)

My question is when the application sellaprime started, and I

```
./bin/sp restart
```

this will make the node down and not restart?

[Erlang Doc](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/init.html#restart-0) say

> The system is restarted **inside** the running Erlang node, which means that the emulator is not restarted. All applications are taken down smoothly, all code is unloaded, and all ports are closed before the system is booted again in the same way as initially started. The same BootArgs are used again.

What does "emulator is not restarted" mean?

If I want to restart a node, what is the right way to do?

By the way, is there any API to know the current release version, like

```
application:which_applications()
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `sb` init script, that is using the `nodetool` script should call `init:restart()` for you. If this is  done, but your node is instead shut down, check your logs for any possible errors (perhaps one of your applications cannot handle a restart?).

Using `init:restart()` is the way to do it though. Here's an example: start an Erlang node with a name (in this case, `test`):

```
$ erl -sname test
Erlang/OTP 18 [erts-7.0] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V7.0  (abort with ^G)
(test@host)1> hello.
hello
(test@host)2>
```

Temporary start another node that will make an RPC call to the first node:

```
$ erl -sname other -noinput -noshell -eval "rpc:call('test@host', init, restart, [])" -s init stop
$
```

Observer the original node being restarted:

```
(test@host)2> Erlang/OTP 18 [erts-7.0] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V7.0  (abort with ^G)
(test@host)1>
```

Comment: I get the log {"init terminating in do_boot",{'cannot load',asn1rt_nif,get_files}}  . How this happened? And why asn1rt will be released, actually I didn't config it in reltool.config

Comment: Perhaps one of your applications depends on it?